# Will a copied spell trigger Prowess?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I cast [Howl of the Horde](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHowl%20of%20the%20Horde%5d) and then cast a [Collateral Damage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bCollateral%20Damage%5d), I know that I do not need to sacrifice additional creatures for the copies based on [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/7857/do-i-need-to-sacrifice-again-if-i-copy-goblin-grenade). However, does each new copy trigger Prowess?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I need to sacrifice again if I copy Goblin Grenade?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/7857/do-i-need-to-sacrifice-again-if-i-copy-goblin-grenade)

Comment: @DrunkCynic The second part of the OP's question isn't answered in the suggested duplicate. Maybe an edit to eliminate the first part and point toward the duplicate, while leaving the second part open.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Collateral damage says:

> As an additional cost to **cast** Collateral Damage ...

Comprehensive Rule 706.10 says:

> To copy a spell ... means to put a copy of it onto the stack; **a copy of a spell isn’t cast**. ...

Per 706.10, the copy of Collateral Damage isn't cast, so you don't have to pay the cost again.

Copying a spell does not trigger Prowess. Prowess triggers when you cast a spell, and, as we previously discovered, copied spells are not cast. A ruling on [Howl of the Horde](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Howl%20of%20the%20Horde) reiterates what we have concluded:

> ... Each copy is created on the stack, so it’s not “cast.” Abilities that trigger when a player casts a spell won’t trigger. ...

Some cards actually copy the card (not the spell) and have you cast the copied card. [Panoptic Mirror](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Panoptic%20Mirror) is a good example. Just to be clear, this would trigger Prowess.

Comment: Note that some effects that seem like they are "copying spells" *do* actually cast. In the case of Isochron Scepter and Panoptic Mirror, a *card* is copied and then the copy is cast. (since you can't "copy" a card from exile onto the stack)

Comment: @HaoYe That is an interesting note, so I included it.

Answer (score 4):

From the card rulings:

> 9/20/2014: [...] Each copy is created on the stack, so it's not "cast". Abilities that trigger when a player casts a spell won't trigger.

Since the copy isn't "cast", you don't have to pay attention to any abilities saying "as an additional cost to cast [card]...". This also means that prowess does not trigger.